# Any way to hook the iPhoneDriver to an existing UIWebView embedded in a Native Application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, selenium, webdriver

My project was a hybrid one, a native application which have an embedded UIWebView,  so in order to run automation test for it, I need handle both native controls and Web Elements.

For native controls, I can use Apple's automation classes,  but for embedded UIWebView, I want to use the Selenium iPhoneDriver.  Anyway to hook the iPhoneDriver to an existing UIWebView embedded in a Native Application? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We're in the same situation, and actively investigating this.  http://code.google.com/p/selenium-uiwebview/ looks promising to us.